# Replacing entire page with ajax response from a frame

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I have a page with frames. In one frame a user's action can cause an ajax request to be sent. The response contains a complete new page and I want to replace the existing page with the response. My problem is that when I try and do that the new content is rendered within the frame the request originated from. How can I replace the entire page and not just the frame?

I've tried:

```
document.open();
document.write(response);
document.close();
```

and:

```
var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
newDoc.write(response);
newDoc.close();
```

But I got the same undesirable results from both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't check right now, but assuming:

- Your Ajax call happens inside a frame one level below the main document
- Your response contains only the body content

You may try the following code:

```
document.parent.body.innerHTML = response;
```

Comment: I am getting: document.parent is undefined. My page looks like this:

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Main </title>
    </head>
    <frameset frameborder=1 border=1 rows="140,*">
        <frame src="mainheader.php>
        <frameset frameborder=1 border=1 cols='75%,25%'>
            <frame src="main.php" name="main">
            <frame src="selection.php" name="selection">
        </frameset>
    </frameset>
    </html>

The request originates from the selection frame.

Comment: This post may give you some insight, Larry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733542/reading-parent-document-from-iframe-and-changing-parent

Comment: I tried both

top.document.body.innerHTML = response; 

and 

parent.document.body.innerHTML = response;

In both case the entire doc was replaced, but only the top frame was rendered. If I look at the page source everything is there, and if I just hit return in the address bar all the frames are rendered. What would prevent it from rendering all the frames when I do the assignment?

Comment: I got this to work by doing this:  
  
top.document.childNodes[0].innerHTML = response;  
  
This works on FF, Chrome, and Safari, but on IE it fails with:  
  
SCRIPT600: Could not set the innerHTML property. Invalid target
element for this operation.